# Windows programming using MinGW

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

Firstly, please forgive my ignorance regarding these matters, I have done a search and not found any comprehensive answers as of yet.

I plan on learning how to develop for Windows, however I am very fond of the GNU toolchain and don't really want to move onto using big environments like Visual Studio until I feel more comfortable with the underlying basics.

From what I understand, one can download the Windows SDK, which contains the headers and libraries needed to build native Windows applications.

Is the SDK literally just a collection of libraries and headers? If so, as my logic goes, it should be possible to point MinGW towards these libraries/headers, and simply build as normal.

When I build using Visual Studio, I can't see what preprocessor directives are being defined, what is being linked in etc. etc., as I am still learning, I like to be able to know exactly what is going on, preferably so I have to manually define, link etc. Hence the question.

So, what I want to know: is my logic correct?

Again, apologies if the question is rudimentary, I am still learning.

P.s. I am planning to develop Windows applications in a windows environment, this is not a question regarding cross-compilation.

Thanks!

Comment: *manually define, link etc* `cl` is the compiler, `link` is the linker. And off you go :]

Comment: So from the command line I can simply invoke cl and link like I would gcc -c and ld? Would this force me to link every WinAPI lib myself/define all the preprocessor macros? :) Basically, I want to have all the nice stuff NOT done for me, so I can learn what is really happening.

Comment: First decide if you want MinGW or not. It´s not clear anymore. And no, the command line options of MS programs are of course not completely the same as of GCC (altough there are some that are equal). And clarify what you want to achieve with the preprocessor. You can write programs without defining anything. Do you want to write headers yourself? Why?

Comment: The actual toolchain is irrelevant to me. I just want to be able to have a less high-level tool for creating windows programs. I want to compile from the cmdline and have to specifically link the relevant libraries. Visual Express does all this for me. I dont want that. Any toolchain is fair game!

Comment: I dont want to write the headers, I want to have specific control over preprocessor definitions such as those which determine things like Unicode etc. And I want to learn which libraries I need to link with instead of the IDE silently doing this for me.Its nothing to do with reinventing the wheel, just getting closer to the reality of the underlying implementation!

Comment: You can always look into the VS project options and change them. Else, as stijn said, just call the compiler directly. With google, you´ll find a list of command line options; same for the linker. Read what a makefile is. And please don´t believe that a preprocessor option is enough for proper Unicode support (in fact, you don´t need it at all). MS make it look like that, but they call C++/CLI still C++ too. They want to sell, not enlighten the people.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I know make, but I didn't know if there was an MS toolchain equivalent. I suppose I could use the GCC make with the MS compiler/linker? Also things such as preprocessor options not being enough for Unicode is exactly why I want to delve deeper into the cmdline for things like this! Thanks.

Comment: @Renzokuken I don´t want to stop you, but get rid of the idea that this direction leads to better Unicode understanding. It´s completely orthogonal. The Wikipedia article about Unicode is a good starting point, together with further detailed research about things like normalization and the exact process of encoding in UTF16/UTF8 etc.

Answer (score 0):

MinGW is not compatible with the official Windows SDK, with one of the reasons
being that the SDK contains many VS-specific things (opposed to the GCC base
on MinGW). MinGW has adapted many of the necessary files, and for many programs
this is enough.

You don´t need to know the VS project settings for some program;
MinGW is still GCC in the core and used as such. If you can compile
programs with GCC on linux, learning how to use MinGW won´t be hard.

If you need functions/structures/etc. which are not yet part of it,
you´re out of luck, other than doing the adaption yourself, which
can be everything between very easy or very hard, depending on the case.
Additionally, proper thread usage is a bit quirky (has some "hidden" pitfalls,
which could go unnoticed in an actual program for years, but then...).

(While this is a disadvantage to VS, you´ll  get C++11/14 (while VS hasn´t
even finished with 11, see [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx)), better optimzation in many cases etc.)

If you´re choosing what exactly to download, look at WinGW-W64 instead of
the "original" old one. The original project somewhat stopped, has poor
lib support compared to W64, no 64bit compiler etc. (and don´t misunderstand
the "W64", it can be used for 32bit programs too)

Comment: `not even close` that's a bit exaggerated, no?

Comment: Well, what "close" means is opinionated of course, but http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx Especially in the second half of the table, there are many "No". At least "not finished" is a fact, and with that speed, it probably won´t be before 2020.

Comment: Just to be precise, it's `MinGW-W64`, not `WinGW-W64`.